# How do I make a version of Armor of Agathys on D&D Beyond that scales with my Pact Magic spell slot levels?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, homebrew, dnd-beyond

A while ago I was given a free spell from my benevolent GM, and I chose Armor of Agathys with the caveat that I could change the damage type (let's leave aside the balance concerns of that for now) and name (to that of my character's patron).

I managed to find the what was claimed to be 'best' way to achieve this, via the D&D Beyond forums was to create a feat that granted a free spell, and I created that (named 'Blessing of the Draumrsteig') and my custom spell. I can't remember the forum post, otherwise I'd share it here.

Unfortunately I can't make the feat public:

> This homebrew Feat has data mapped to it that is licensed content or private homebrew. This typically occurs when licensed or private homebrew spells are linked to the Feat.

I did have a link to my homebrew spell but that's also been marked as too small a variation to be shared.

What I have noticed is that I can't get it to scale like Armor of Agathys does. And I'm not sure how to do that either (I'm also not certain what I've done to get to this stage, so bear with me if my details are off). It's showing the spell as 'at will' which I think is a concession from advice I found on the DnDBeyond forum...?

This is how it appears:

[image: screenshot of the spell section on a DnD Beyond character sheet. The custom spell is shown with the text below it giving the homebrew feat name.]

As you can see the effect only shows the number 5 and a heart symbol, and hasn't scaled with my pact slot level.

How can I achieve this scaling effect on temporary HP and damage?

Comment: @Daveman Even partial answers belong in answers, not in comments.

Answer (score 9):

If you check "At Higher Level Scaling" and select "Spell Scale", you should be able to add the same conditions that Armor of Agathys does in the "At Higher Levels" section with the damage type altered:

[image: Edit Spell on D&D Beyond: At Higher Levels section]

I tested this out and it works and notably I cannot share it because it is too similar to Armor of Agathys.  Here it is auto-leveling to 4th level:
[image: Spell on Character Sheet]

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: I thought I had done this, and it looks like I have, but this is still the result on my character sheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPQJY.jpg

Comment: That looks correct for a 1st level casting, if you level it up to 4th level should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUxQl.png

Comment: @FlashbackJon maybe it's how I've added it to the character via a feat?

Answer (score 6):

### The easy way:

*(...as long as you have bought the spell in DnDBeyond. It can't just be shared to you, you must own it yourself.)*

- Go to Create Homebrew Spell.
- In the **Use an existing spell as a template:** box, select Armor of Agathys.
- Click the **Create** button.
- Modify it how you like.

[image: Create Homebrew Spell, Use an existing spell as a template: SPELL SCHOOL All SPELL Armor of Agathys, CREATE]

Comment: For some reason I don't see Armor of Agathys

Comment: I suspect the homebrew thing is limiting you to content that your account actually owns, rather than letting you use anything you have access to via campaign sharing. I depend on sharing for all the paid content and I'm pretty sure the only spells I can see in that dropdown are the basic rules ones.

Comment: @Carcer ahhh and Armor of Agathys is not in the basic rules

Comment: Added a note that you have to own the spell

Comment: @Adeptus if you go through with this, can you edit it later? If so, what are the details I'm missing to create my own version if you know?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage yes once it's created, it's just like any other homebrew. You can edit it all you like. https://i.stack.imgur.com/43lFH.png

Comment: @Adeptus mine looks exactly the same, so I'm guessing it's how I've added it via a feat.